# What is a manifest.yml file in cloud foundry and why do i need it?

Tags: java, sap-cloud-foundry

Why do I need to add this file to my JAVA projects before deploying the project on cloud foundry? Is it mandatory?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**What is a manifest.yml file in cloud foundry?**

The file is an application deployment descriptor.This means that it contains information needed to deploy the application on cloud doundry e.g. name of the application, path to the application .war or .jar file and so on.

**why do i need it?**
It is not needed. The file is optional. Although using the file is helpful so that we don't have to give the application name, path etc in the cli command when deploying the file every time. 
The cf push command looks for a manifest.yml file in the directory from where the push command is executed and uses the deployment values from this file.

**Why do i need to add this file to my JAVA projects before deploying the project on cloud foundry?**
As explained above, one does not need it.

**Is it mandatory?**
Not at all

Answer (score 1):

To deploy an APP you have several options. The standard is to add the manifest.yml

you can find more information about it [here ( CF devguide )](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/manifest.html). CF need to know several things and you can define them in this file. please have a look into the Attribute Reference to see what you can enter into this file.

Comment: It is not a requirement to use manifest.yml. It's preference. You can specify everything using various `cf` cli commands if you prefer. The manifest.yml has some advantages though, like that it can be checked into source control (don't put sensitive info in it) and it can set things like env variables and bind services in bulk. It can't do everything though, like it can't be used for service bindings which require the `-c` argument. At any rate, it's fairly common to use one but it's your choice.